# Android authentication based on user touch behavior

Tags: android, pattern-matching, biometrics

I am working on continuous device authentication based on user touch behavior, I could able to capture touch data from sample launcher app.  Touch data includes coordinates, touch area, pressure, distance .
Collected touch data saved in sqlite db.
Now ,In order to identify test data either legitimate user or intruder, what is the best algorithm that we incorporate here ?. does android have any inbuilt machine learning algorithm support ? or any machine learning library in java ? 
I have checked weka library, that looks too complex for me.

Please give any suggestions on this. whether is this feasible.